# Bundle contains data but in the Fragment it is Null

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I pass a `bundle` from an activity to a `fragment` using `setArgument`, and when I retrieve it back from the `fragment` using `getArgument`, i found it is `null` despite it has values.

In the below code, I am showing how I retrieve the `bundle` in the `fragment` activity.

For mre clarificaion, I have an `activity_1` that passes a `bundle` to `activity_2`. In `activity_2`i instantiate 2 `fragments` and assign them to `actionTabs`. From `activity_2`, i have checked the `bundle` and it has values, based on that test I passed them to the 2 `fragments`. In the one of the `Fragments` I retrieve it using `getArgument` and it is `null`. please see the code below ffro more clarification how i retrieve it.

**Code_Fragment**

```
public class Sub_Frag extends Fragment {
private final Bundle dataBundle = getArguments();
...
...
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle  
savedInstanceState) {
//here i check if the bundle is null or not, and it is null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be calling this when the fragment is created. Change line 2 to read:

```
private Bundle dataBundle;
```

And get the arguments in onCreateView:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle  
savedInstanceState) {

    dataBundle = getArguments();

}
```

Comment: but how the variable databundle is declared final without initialisation?

Comment: Why does it have to be `final`?

Comment: i know it wil work without the final modifier but since the bundle=fetArgument must be read only, i think, it should be final, or what do u think?

Comment: Well, those sorts of decisions are up to you. I'm just letting you know that you need to call `getArguments()` sometime after the fragment has been created and initialized.